# how to output the result to a file in monogodb

Tags: mongodb

I wan to list all database in Monogodb and output to a txt file, but it did not work.

```
mongo 127.0.0.1/test -eval 'var c= show databases;' >>db_list.txt
```

the error message is

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.12
connecting to: 127.0.0.1/test
2016-12-06T12:12:32.456-0700 SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

anyone knows how to make this work. I appreciate any help.

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22565231/printing-mongo-query-output-to-a-file-while-in-the-mongo-shell

Comment: also this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/ because you should user js methods instead of regular mongo commands. so show databases should be replaced with db.adminCommand('listDatabases')

Comment: Thanks, it did not work after used db.adminCommand('listDatabases'). the error is listdatabases is not defined.

Comment: pasting the answer for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use eval and list databases directly on a shell, the following query should be helpful.

```
mongo test --eval "printjson(db.adminCommand('listDatabases'))"
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.10
connecting to: test
{
        "databases" : [
                {
                        "name" : "local",
                        "sizeOnDisk" : 73728,
                        "empty" : false
                },
                {
                        "name" : "m034",
                        "sizeOnDisk" : 11911168,
                        "empty" : false
                },
                {
                        "name" : "test",
                        "sizeOnDisk" : 536576,
                        "empty" : false
                }
        ],
        "totalSize" : 12521472,
        "ok" : 1
}
```

This will list all the collection names in a particular DB.

```
mongo test --eval "printjson(db.getCollectionNames())"
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.10
connecting to: test
[
        "aaa",
        "areamodel",
        "email",
        "hex",
        "key",
        "mel",
        "multi",
        "ques",
        "rich"
]
```

A sample execution for reference (screenshot)
[image: A sample execution for reference]

Comment: thanks, it worked on Linux. the command is mongo 127.0.0.1 -eval "var c= printjson(db.adminCommand('listDatabases'))" >>db_list.txt . @satish chennupati, thanks so much.

Comment: happy to help my friend. :D

Comment: I am not a big fan of using image in an answer. It simply does not add any value. Instead you should copy/paste your code.

Comment: @styvane it was spur of the moment. will try to avoid pasting images as answers from next time. Rather i would add code first and can later append an image as an example if needed.

Comment: You can start by editing the answer. You already said something like that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40896625/retrieve-field-value-from-array-of-sub-document/40897012?noredirect=1#comment69008123_40897012) but did not delete the answer.

Comment: thanks for your updated solution . @ satish chennupati. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Instead of test you can go simply,
**mongo db_name query.js > out.json**

here query.js contains any query like:
**printjson( db.adminCommand('listDatabases') )**